# What are the various fonts / typefaces used here?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-identification, typefaces, font-face

I  *love*  kinetic typography, and the latest video by David Guetta, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YO9THtRWb2s uses it in an interesting way. Instead of just using text as a 2D element, they've made text a part of the environment.

**Could you guys please help me out with the various fonts w/ typefaces used in this here? (images linked)**

I've added the images in this imgur album link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXxr6.jpg

Thanks in Anticipation :)

Images:

1. [image: Sans-serif of somesort]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. [image]

Comment: -1: This question does not show any research effort. Screenshots would be good.

Comment: Yea, or at least specific times when the texts appear. Youtube even allows you to get the url to specific time in the video. I'm gonna give this minus as well.

Comment: Guys come on! This is a new user, let's show a little warmth. Basically, the reason you've been downvoted is that you've given us little to work with. It's like dropping a link and saying 'you do all the work!' Give us a bit of backstory, accurate time links as @Lollero said or screenshots as e100 suggested. Show us that you have at least had a go at finding out, that way we don't feel like we're doing your job, just helping a little.

Comment: @Lollero Wow, I've totally come off as an asshole when I come to think of it. Sorry guys, I should've made an honest effort. Will get to it right away.

Comment: @e100: Well, the fact that I can't add screenshots doesn't help either (I'm a new user)

Comment: @Lollero Would you care to enlighten me on this? I would like to do that, as you've suggested.

Comment: @DanielHanly Thanks a lot mate. Appreciate it. But I need a reputation of 10 to get to post pics, and I really don't know how to make "timestamped" youtube links. I do agree that I did sound a bit stupid, but it wasn't intentional.

Thanks a lot. I really do appreciate you sticking up for a n00b :)

Comment: @Ameen For now, add links and me or someone can change those as images.

Comment: And if you want to post links from youtube you need to get to the position of the specific thing in the timeline and then right click the video and 2nd list item should say something like "copy current position url"

Comment: No Worries mate. There we are, I upvoted you to relax the downvotes a little. You nearly have 10 reputation now

Comment: @Lollero I've added the images to an imgur album and posted the link in my question, hope this helps. And Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I wouldn't spend so much time in finding the particular fonts.<br> Use pages like these to find similar fonts: - [dafont](http://dafont.com)
- [fawnt](http://www.fawnt.com/)
- [abstractfonts](http://www.abstractfonts.com/)
- or [fontsqirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Comment: Try running some of these through http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: try http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ <br />
or http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 99% sure the font in picture #9 is ITC Avant Garde book. Many of the fonts displayed in these pictures looks made by professional. Try google either Linotype or ITC. Perhaps you´ll find something there.

Answer (score 3):

1. Looks like a tightly tracked Avant Garde Bold Oblique:

[image]

2. Could be either Avant Garde again or a Futura Bold, hard to well with only three characters:

[image]

3. Looks like Eagle Black, tightly tracked with the counters removed:

[image]

4. Unknown, maybe someone else will recognise it.
5. Hard to say with only two characters, looks similar to Gotham or Proxima Nova. I'm going with Proxima Nova simply because H&F type tester isn't working properly:

[image]

6. We've already had some Avant Garde, so it's likely suspect here:

[image]

7. Eagle Black again:

[image]

8. Unknown.
9. Avant Garde again:

[image]

Comment: #8 looks an awful lot like a heavy, rounded version of Clan. And I'd say #5 is definitely more likely Proxima Nova than Gotham—too lazy to double check, but I don't recall the shoulder on the h in Gotham tapering that much towards the stem.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not sure about Clan; the lowercase 'h' is slightly taller than the uppercase 'O', and has a slight angle on the ascender. Pretty darn close otherwise. It's certainly unusual; the lack of contrast and extreme weight and condensed forms are suggesting Knockout to me. Unfortunately the Hoefler & Co's type tester isn't working at the moment, so I can't get screen shot to confirm this. Given that Knockout might have been used for #8, it could also be a candidate for #5.

Comment: Yeah, just checked it now that I’m actually at the computer and have the fonts to look at. I don’t have a rounded version of Clan, but if #5 is supposed to be one, it’s one where the angle on the ascender has been removed.

Comment: Testing with Gotham and Proxima Nova, it also seems I was misremembering—there **is** that much tapering on the h in Gotham, but the h in Proxima has more space between the stem and the leg. Comparing side by side, it looks more like Gotham Ultra than Proxima Nova. (Also, I just realised this question is three years old!)